# Creating a Fibonacci Sequence in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, fibonacci

I wanted to create a program which will list a number of terms in the Fibonacci sequence. The number of terms has to be specified by the user. I am quite new to programming and Visual Studio, can someone help me out?

Comment: I have made a form which has two text boxes, one for displaying the sequence[TextBox1], and one for user input [TextBox2] as to how many terms the user wants to display along with a generate button [btnGenerate].

Comment: Please state your programming language so that the expert in that can see your question.